# Gson object deserialization - null pointer failure

Tags: java, json, gson

I have no idea why this is not working. In a different project it works without problem with more complicated objects (that even have nested objects).

Do i miss something painfully obvious?

How my json looks in file:

```
{
    "masterPort": 5000,
    "errorLog": "aaaa"
}
```

Part of function where i load the json:

```
File configFile = new File(pathToConfig);
try {
    BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(configFile));
    Configuration a = gson.fromJson(br, Configuration.class); // <---- here it fails :(
} catch ( catch blocks ) { /*error handling*/ }
```

And my configuration class:

```
public class Configuration {
    int masterPort = 5000;
    String errorLog = "xvdsaf";
}
```

Stack trace this is the whole thing and it baffles me:

```
java.lang.NullPointerException
    at config.MasterConfiguration.load(MasterConfiguration.java:37)
    at config.MasterConfiguration.load(MasterConfiguration.java:30)
    at bs.Manager.loadConfiguration(Manager.java:43)
    at bs.Manager.main(Manager.java:22)
```

Comment: Post the exception stack trace. Have you initialized `gson`?

Comment: It very much looks like `gson` is `null`.

Comment: posted, and i have initialised gson.

Comment: From the stack trace, that's the only thing that can cause a `NullPointerException`. Prove otherwise.

Comment: LOOK at my answer have you initialized it this way

Comment: Thank you guys, one of the devs had a good idea to set the gson object to null (to "save" memory). but it was not obvious to me at first. *facepalm*

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should initialize the gson object

```
Gson gson = (new GsonBuilder()).create();
```